# RecordRTC - Playing recordings on Safari fails

Tags: macos, safari, video-recording, recordrtc

I am using RecordRTC to allow my application user to record their video and upload. This works perfectly fine with Chrome and Mozila Firefox but Safari having trouble playing recorded videos.
I research for the same and found `mimeType: 'video/webm\;codecs=vp8'` to be used for safari. However this still won't work on Safari browsers. (mac OS x and iOS)

Can someone please help me with this? I have multiple users working on different operating systems and working on different browsers and I want to make sure RecordRTC works for all of them.

I am open to change/ switch to any other alternative if available to implement this feature with cross-browser support of course.

I found Twilio but I am not sure whether Twilio supports standalone recordings or not? I mean I just want single user to go on a page record a video and upload.

Please see below my RecordRTC configuration if it helps:

```
const options = {
      type: 'video',
      mimeType: 'video/webm\;codecs=vp8',
      bitsPerSecond: 128000,
      timeSlice: 1000
    };
```

After user completes the recording, I am converting it to a blob and append it to the formData to save it to the server:

```
var recordedBlob: Blob = recordRTC.getBlob();
formData.append('files', recordedBlob, this.courseComponent?.courseComponent?.name + '.webm');
```

This recorded video plays fine in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari it Fails.
Please if you can guide me through this it will be great help to me.
Thanks.

Below are the console log snaps:

1.browser does not support media recorder api

[image: browser does not support media recorder api]

2. when tried to play the recorded video

[image: when tried to play the recorded video]

3. says browser does not support media recorder api and try using whammyRecorder

[image: says browser does not support media recorder api and try using whammyRecorder]

Comment: Twilio does not support standalone recording, only recording a call that goes via Twilio servers as part of a Group Room. How is this code failing in Safari? What is the error message?

Comment: hi @philnash,
I have updated the question with the console log errors I get when I tried to record and play the video. Basically it says Your browser does not support the Media Recorder API. And within the video player it shows blank and broken play icon (Safari). Here's the link [RecordRTC Experimental](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) I tried this to test RecordRTC on Mac Safari and iPhone's Safari it fails there too. Is there any other way to achieve this if you can help

Comment: Yep, it seems something changed in Safari to break RecordRTC. I would recommend you follow and add your comments to [this issue on the RecordRTC GitHub](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/655).